# Removing URL Trailing Slash

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I built a blog (which I hope to get online today), but recently came across .htaccess rewrites for better url redirection, but I'm having a few issues.  I've sorted out the actual Rewrite using the `RewriteRule`, but then came across the issue of "Trailing Slashes vs No Trailing Slashes".

I decided to go with **No Trailing Slashes**, but figured that because google see them both as unique addresses, I better use some sort of redirect so that the `/` is removed from the url.

Here is the `htaccess` code that I have so far:

```
Options -MultiViews

DirectoryIndex articles.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    

RewriteRule ^articles/([\w-]+)/?$               articles.php?cat=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^articles/([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$      articles.php?cat=$1&currentpage=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)/([\w-]+)/?$       article.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^articles articles.php
RewriteRule ^articles/ articles [R=301,L] /* Problem Line */
```

Everything is working fine with all of the above code except the final line because when I add a slash to the URL it's not redirecting and removing the slash.  How can this be acheived?  Is there a fix so that the trailing slash on **any** page is automatically removed?

Answer (score 0):

Have it this way:

```
Options -MultiViews
DirectoryIndex articles.php
RewriteEngine On

## Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [NE,R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d    
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^articles/([\w-]+)/?$  articles.php?cat=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^articles/([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ articles.php?cat=$1&currentpage=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ article.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^articles/?$ articles.php [L]
```